# An unrecoverable error occurred

Tags: 6

My site has run fine for some time; recently, when I upload an image, it always shows the following error message.

[image]

The first time I upload the image is OK, but when I create the second article, and upload an image, it shows the above error; the upload button disappears. Does anyone know how to correct it, and what's the reason of this error?

If I disable the site cache, the error disappears, and uploading the image is fine.

What's wrong with my site? What should I do to fix it?

Comment: We would need more info to go on. All modules and versions installed. Watchdog entries and server logs. Then we may be able to help you.

Comment: Jeremy French, i have updated the questions. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The error is most likely that you in your browser have cached the form. So when you go to the form page, instead of getting a fresh form, the browser shows you the cached page.

Since each form has a unique id and can only be submitted once (security reason), you get that error instead. I've seen similar things happen with IE/varnish when varnish was incorrectly setup.

To test, try clearing your browser's cache where this happens and try to load the page again.

Comment: i have tried your ways. but it still doesn't work.